# I can't find out my mistake in displaying database data in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-database

I am working on a Django project. I have to display database data in the Django template but I can't find out my mistake in my code that is not allowing me to display data on the HTML page.

> views.py

```
def viewposts(request):
     posts = NewPost.objects.all()

     return render(request,"network/index.html",{
         "posts" : posts,
     })
```

Here is my model:

> models.py

```
class NewPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    post = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __str__(self):
         return f"post : {post} || user: {user} || timestamp: {timestamp} "
```

> HTML template

```
<div id="posts">
        {% for posts in posts %}
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h4>{{ posts.user }} || {{ posts.timestamp }}</h4>
                    <h3>{{ posts.post }}</h3>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        {% empty %}
            <h6>No post availabel </h6>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   path("", views.index, name="index"),
   path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
   path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
   path("register", views.register, name="register"),
   path("index/",views.NewPostMaker,name="post"),
   path("index/",views.viewposts,name="posts")
]
```

I know I have done a silly mistake on any part of my code but I can hardly find it out. When I fill-up the form, data is stored in the database but I can't display them on the HTML page.

Comment: You have two `index/` patterns, hence it will fire the `NewPostMaker`, not the `viewposts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined two paths for `index/`. This means that if the user visits the `index/` URL, the first view will "fire" and render the template. As a result it will fire `NewPostMaker`, not `viewposts`.

You thus should define *one* view, where you probably will have to merge the logic of the two views into one, and thus implement this as:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index, name="index'),
   path('login', views.login_view, name='login'),
   path('logout', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
   path('register', views.register, name='register'),
   path('index/', views.viewposts, name='posts')
]
```